# Converting a string to dictionary in python

Tags: python

I have the following string :

```
str = "{application.root.category.id:2}"
```

I would like to convert the above to a dictionary data type in python as in :

```
dict = {application.root.category.id:2}
```

I tried using eval() and this is the error I got:

> AttributeError: java package 'application' has no attribute "root"

My current python is of <2.3 and I cannot update the python to >2.3 .

Any solutions ?

Comment: What should be the key of the dictionary item?

Comment: can you explain the `java package` thing?

Comment: Do you want `{application.root.category.id: 2}` or `{"application.root.category.id": 2}`? Your problem is that `application.root.category.id` cannot be evaluated.

Comment: This question isn't in any way version-specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, 'dict' is the type name so not good for the variable name.

The following, does precisely as you asked...

```
a_dict = dict([str.strip('{}').split(":"),])
```

But if, as I expect, you want to add more mappings to the dictionary, a different approach is required.

Answer (score 5):

Python dictionaries have keys that needn't be strings; therefore, when you write `{a: b}` you need the quotation marks around `a` if it's meant to be a string. (`{1:2}`, for instance, maps the *integer* 1 to the integer 2.)

So you can't just pass something of the sort you have to `eval`. You'll need to parse it yourself. (Or, if it happens to be easier, change whatever generates it to put quotation marks around the keys.)

Exactly how to parse it depends on what your dictionaries might actually look like; for instance, can the values themselves be dictionaries, or are they always numbers, or what? Here's a simple and probably too crude approach:

```
contents = str[1:-1]        # strip off leading { and trailing }
items = contents.split(',') # each individual item looks like key:value
pairs = [item.split(':',1) for item in items] # ("key","value"), both strings
d = dict((k,eval(v)) for (k,v) in pairs) # evaluate values but not strings
```

Comment: For security reasons, I'd rather use `int(v)` or `eval(v,{},{})` instead of the plain `eval(v)`. Compare `eval("os.remove('/tmp/a')", {}, {})` ("name 'os' is not defined") against `eval("os.remove('/tmp/a')")` ("No such file or directory: '/tmp/a'").

Comment: Yes. Generally using `eval` (especially its simple one-arg form) is a bad, bad idea. I just lazily did it because the OP did :-).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose I have a string

```
str='{1:0,2:3,3:4}'
str=str.split('{}')
mydict={}
for every in str1.split(','):
    z=every.split(':')
    z1=[]
    for every in z:
        z1.append(int(every))
    for k in z1:
        mydict[z1[0]]=z1[1]
```

output:
    `mydict
    {1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 4}`