# Convert HTTPResponse object to dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, httpresponse

I'm trying to turn this object into something I can work with in my program.  I need to store the message-id to a database.  Short of flat-out parsing it, can I just turn this whole thing into a dictionary somehow?

Here is where I'm at with some IDLE testing:

```
>>> response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
>>> response.getheaders()
[('Server', 'nginx/1.6.0'), ('Date', 'Sat, 07 Jun 2014 00:32:45 GMT'), ('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=ISO-8859-1'), ('Transfer-Encoding', 'chunked'), ('Connection', 'close'), ('Cache-Control', 'max-age=1')]
>>> response.read()
b'{"message-count":"1","messages":[{"to":"11234567890","message-id":"02000000300D8F21","status":"0","remaining-balance":"1.82720000","message-price":"0.00620000","network":"302220"}]}'
```

After a half hour of sifting through google I was able to turn it into a string with:

```
>>> response.response.decode('utf-8')
>>> print(response)
'{"message-count":"1","messages":[{"to":"11234567890","message-id":"02000000300D8F21","status":"0","remaining-balance":"1.82720000","message-price":"0.00620000","network":"302220"}]}'
>>> type(response)
<class 'str'>
```

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10978908/converting-a-string-to-dictionary-in-python) but here is what I get:

```
>>> a_dict = dict([response.strip('{}').split(":"),])
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#79>", line 1, in <module>
  a_dict = dict([response.strip('{}').split(":"),])
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 9; 2 is required
```

Maybe I'm going about this all wrong.  What's the quickest way to turn this object into a dictionary or something else I can easily work with?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Load it via [`json.load()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/json.html#json.load):

```
import json
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
result = json.loads(response.readall().decode('utf-8'))
message_id = result['messages'][0]['message-id']
```

Comment: OK, after I convert it to a string and decode it I am able to run json.loads() on it.  How do I access the data in the messages key?  if it was a dictionary I'd do: `result['messages']['message-id'] and I'd get a value back but I get `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`  -- Can you edit your answer to document the steps required so it's useful to future google searches?

Comment: @Chevron when you call `load()` or `loads()` you get a python data structure (`dict` in your case).

Comment: @Chevron there is a list under `result['messages']`. You need to do: `result['messages'][0]['message-id']`.

Comment: My hero.  On to the next upcoming roadblock/learning tool!  Thanks @alecxe!

Comment: For this to work I also need to decode utf8 and use json.loads() instead of json.load().